# Matlab and R functions for fft(): N-point FFT and dimension issue

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, self-study

In MATLAB, `Y = fft(X,n,dim)` returns the Fourier transform along the dimension `dim`. For example, if `X` is a matrix, then `fft(X,n,2)` returns the n-point Fourier transform of each row. However, in R is different. Do you know any function to solve this; so that takes into account `n` and `dim`, to get a `n` length complex vector? See that in the example that `n>ncol(X)`.

## MATLAB code

```
Fs = 1000; % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs; % Sampling period
L = 1000; % Length of signal
t = (0:L-1)*T; % Time vector

x1 = cos(2*pi*50*t); % First row wave
x2 = cos(2*pi*150*t); % Second row wave
x3 = cos(2*pi*300*t);  % Third row wave

n = 2^nextpow2(L);
dim = 2;
X = [x1; x2; x3];

Y_right = fft(X,n,dim); %Result: 3*1024 complex double
```

[image]

```
 Y_wrong = fft(X); %Result: 3*1000 complex double (I am looking for the above result)
```

[image]

## R code

```
Fs <- 1000
T <- 1/Fs
L <- 1000
t <- (0:(L-1))*T

x1 <- cos(2*pi*50*t)
x2 <- cos(2*pi*150*t)
x3 <- cos(2*pi*300*t)

n<-2^ceiling(log2(abs(L)))
dim <- 2
X <- t(matrix(c(x1, x2, x3), ncol=3))

Y <- fft(X) 
# Result: 3*1000 cplx and it is not the same as `Y_wrong` (operates along each row) 
#To get Y_wrong:

Y <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=1000)

for (i in 1:ncol(X)) {
Y[,i] <- fft(X[,i], inverse = T)
}
```

[image]

My aim is to get `Y_right`, and Y think that by using `apply` we get the same as `Y_wrong`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What specifically in the documentation do you not understand? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.1/topics/fft

Comment: How two use the two last arguments of Matlab in R. So that I can get a 3*1024 matrix in R, and not a 1000.

Comment: @fina then that's a programming and not a signal processing question, and you might want to migrate it to stackoverflow

Comment: I've already done it... but seems that nobody knows, I can remove it if necessary.

Comment: You can't. The FFT on R operates only on vectors, not on matrices.You have to write a loop and do one FFT per row

Comment: I thought this, but what do you think about the lengths of the rows? it changes due to `n`

Comment: Hi: Use apply which goes over rows or columns depending on whether you use 1 or 2. So, if X is the matrix, apply(X, 1, fft(;.row)) or apply(X, 2, fft(.col)). you may have to transform the result. I forget.

Comment: @markleeds hmmm but that should be an answer; not a comment...

Comment: @markleeds I agree with Fat32, please write an answer. I've been working all afternoon on it; it seems it can be approached differently. There is a package that may help: `ffwtols`; however, the n remains unclear to me. We get a matrix of 1000 rows by the standard `fft`, but of 1024 in Matlab because of `n`. I'm hesitating about the meaning...and thank you all of you, my apologies not to have enough rate to reward your comments. I need 15 for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R allows you to loop over rows or columns through the use of the **apply** family of functions. Note that *apply* is not necessarily faster than looping but more in line with the functional programming nature of R. There are other *apply* functions such as *lapply, vapply, sapply* etc but for your purposes, *apply* should suffice.  Also, note that you may have to transpose the result using `t(result)`. 1 means go over rows and 2 means go over columns. So, if X is the matrix,

```
apply(X, 1, fft) does the fft of the rows.

apply(X, 2, fft) does the fft of the columns.
```

Note that the use of .row or .col is my convention. I could have used x, y , or z because that's just a dummy variable from apply's point of view.

Also, you can type `? apply` in R in order to obtain the help for apply. Sometimes they can be kind of obscure but atleast they tell you what arguments are available.

Comment: @Fat32: Thanks for edits.

Comment: @Fat32 and mark leeds, I am not sure it is correct. I give more information on the question to clarify this. I've done, just in case the same as `apply` but with the loop `for`.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598542/how-to-run-n-points-fft-in-r) can help.

Comment: @fina You originally asked a question on how to get R to do an FFT over a matrix as simple as MATLAB without looping. The answer as **apply** function is correct. [btw: `fft(.row)` does not make sense to me, wouldn't it be just `fft` according to online documentation ?]... But now you change the focus of the question on the **size** of the DFT/FFT and found the answer as zero padding ;-)

Comment: its ok. You got the validation.

Comment: @Fat32: you are correct. If I wanted to use .row or .col, I should have written apply(X, 1, function(.row) fft(.row)). Otherwise, it's apply(X, 1, fft). Thanks for correction.

Comment: @Fat32: Thanks again for useful edits.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the solution. Looking into the function code by doing `open ftt` (matlab) we can see:

```
%   FFT(X,N) is the N-point FFT, padded with zeros if X has less
%   than N points and truncated if it has more.
%
%   FFT(X,[],DIM) or FFT(X,N,DIM) applies the FFT operation across the
%   dimension DIM.
```

Therefore, if `X` has less than `n` points, the vectors should be padded with zeros at the end:

```
padding_X<- matrix(0, ncol=n-L, nrow=3)  
X<-cbind(X,padding_X)
```

Then we get a matrix of 3*1024, padded with zeros. The following thing to do is the fft:

```
Y <- matrix(0, nrow=3, ncol=ncol(X))

for (i in 1:nrow(X)) {
  Y[i,] <- fft(X[i,], inverse = T)
}
```

And, voilà:
[image]